# Webpack Config Global Not Defined Error Node

Tags: webpack

I am trying to add in a property to my `webpack.config.js` file that will prevent webpack from injecting its path as a value into my global object that is being populated by expressJS.

Some property values look like this when the global object is called: `originalUrl: '/app/page/bundle.js' ----- //Rather than '/app/page/2'`

From my research it appears that the `node` option is the right solution, but after I added `node: { global: false }` I noticed a `Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined` error that came as a result. Did I place `node` in the wrong position within my file.

**Current setup:**

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./public/index.js",
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "/dist",
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {   
                test: /\.js$/, 
                exclude: /node_modules/, 
                loader: "babel-loader"
            },
            {   
                test: /\.jsx$/, 
                exclude: /node_modules/, 
                loader: "babel-loader"
            }
        ]
    },
    node: {
        global: false
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The `node` configuration is in the right place.

As you set `global` to false, it is not going to be available hence the "global is not defined" error that you've got.

Edit: set it to `true` so it will be available for ExpressJS.

As the documentation says:

- true: Provide a polyfill.
- "mock": Provide a mock that implements the expected interface but has little or no functionality.
- "empty": Provide an empty object.
- false: Provide nothing. Code that expects this object may crash with a ReferenceError. Code that attempts to import the module using require('modulename') may trigger a Cannot find module "modulename" error.

Comment: Well that makes sense haha. I guess I assumed that setting it to `false` meant it would prevent webpack from manipulating the global object from its state in ExpressJS and not represent the removal the object from the bundle.js. If I were to store the global object with just the expressJS information as I mentioned in my question, would I achieve this with passing `"empty"` or `"mock"`?